# Where does `OpaqueJSValue`in `JavaScriptCore` come from?

Tags: ios, c, webkit, javascriptcore

I cannot find definition of `OpaqueJSValue` in `JavaScriptCore` framework. Only valuable hints about it are in `Base.h` and `APICast.h` (in both files same code):

```
typedef const struct OpaqueJSValue* JSValueRef;
typedef struct OpaqueJSValue* JSObjectRef;
```

So we know that other types are based on it, but what is `OpaqueJSValue` itself? Or at least where does it come from? Where is it defined?

Trying to read a value of the `OpaqueJSValue` in the debugger results in error saying that the debugger also doesn't know what it is:

```
(lldb) e *variable
error: incomplete type 'const OpaqueJSValue' where a complete type is required
forward declaration of 'OpaqueJSValue'
```

Where variable is `JSValueRef` type so in fact `const struct OpaqueJSValue*`.

I cloned repository with JavaScriptCore framework, libWTF and webkit but I have not found anything in those.

Sources:

- WebKit https://github.com/WebKit/webkit.git
- JavaScriptCore and
  libWTF: https://opensource.apple.com/release/ios-110.html

---

I'll be happy to update the title and body of that question to make it more descriptive and easy to find, however since I really have no clue what `OpaqueJSValue` is and how it works I'm unable to ask about it in more specific way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no definition of OpaqueJSValue. Actually JSValueRef is just a opaque pointer, and there are some convertions between JSValueRef and JSC::JSValue as you can see in "API\APICast.h". JSC::JSValue is the internal data structure.